# In select option , all options should be selected and the user should not be able to change it

Tags: html

I have to create a select dropdown using HTML in which the users have to select all options.

```
<select multiple>

<option value="thriller" selected>thriller</option>
<option value="action" selected >action</option>
<option value="horror" selected >horror</option>
<option value="romance" selected>romance</option>


</select>
```

If the users clicks on any option, only the particular option remains selected. I have to use the selected options to set up values using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it only in HTML, the following code works

```
<select multiple>
<option value="thriller" selected disabled>thriller</option>
<option value="action" selected disabled>action</option>
<option value="horror" selected disabled>horror</option>
<option value="romance" selected disabled>romance</option>

</select>
```

**However it wont work for IE and you will unable to post data.**

In Javascript, this code will work

```
    <select multiple onclick="fun();">
```

Inside script tag, add the following code

```
    function fun()
    {
            var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
            var length = sel.options.length;
            for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                    sel.getElementsByTagName('option')[i].selected = 'selected';
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your question is only tagged HTML, i must say :

**you can't do that in HTML.**

You will need a client-side script, like javascript or, better, jQuery to listen on selection event, then to manipulate the HTML for it's complies with your goal.

Of course, a new langage, even an easy one like jQuery, need some learning. Follow some tutorial, you won't loose your time.